# Linking native .so in Google Dataproc Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc, freeling

I have a native library (Freeling), which I have compiled using cmake and make natively and installed through cluster startup actions (so, it should exist in master and each worker)

Even so, I'm getting this error when calling `System.loadLibrary`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no Jfreeling in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
```

I've tried using the following properties to get the program to find the library (It's called in a static block of code)

```
      "properties": {
        "spark.driver.extraClassPath": "/usr/local/share/freeling/APIs/java/Jfreeling.jar:/usr/local/lib/libfreeling.so",
        "spark.executor.extraClassPath": "/usr/local/share/freeling/APIs/java/Jfreeling.jar:/usr/local/lib/libfreeling.so",
        "spark.executor.extraLibraryPath": "/usr/local/lib/libfreeling.so",
        "spark.driver.extraLibraryPath": "/usr/local/lib/libfreeling.so",
        "spark.executorEnv.LD_PRELOAD": "/usr/local/lib/libfreeling.so",
        "spark.yarn.dist.files": "/usr/local/lib/libfreeling.so",
        "spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.LD_PRELOAD": "libfreeling.so",
        "spark.files": "/usr/local/lib/libfreeling.so",
        "spark.executorEnv.LD_LIBRARY_PATH": "libfreeling.so"
      },
      "jarFileUris": [
        "file:///usr/local/share/freeling/APIs/java/Jfreeling.jar",
        "file:///usr/local/lib/libfreeling.so"
      ],
```

Comment: Are you using YARN?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try putting your library under `/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/`? In `/etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh`, it has

```
# Spark got rid of SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH in 1.0
# It has properties for extraLibraryPaths, but this is more extensible
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:${HADOOP_HOME}/lib/native
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add /usr/local/share/freeling/APIs/java/Jfreeling.jar to your CLASSPATH, and /usr/local/share/freeling/APIs/java/libJfreeling.so to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.